# Hotkeys for Totem in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, vlc, totem

I'm looking for a way to control the playback of Totem Movie Player even when I'm not focused on the window itself. I have done it with VLC using the instructions on the following link: http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_use_VLC_for_transcription_in_linux  . However, VLC distorts the audio quality of the files I want to play (both .wma and .ogg files). Totem gives me great quality, but I have to be focused on the window to be able to control the playback. Any advice, or do I just have to stick with VLC?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **Help** > **Content** (open it by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>) - here the highlight:

<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>: Go back 15 seconds

<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>: Go forward 60 seconds

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>: Go back 5 seconds

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>: Go forward 15 seconds

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>: Go back 3 minutes

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>: Go forward 10 minutes

Comment: I've tried those, but they don't work unless I'm actually focused on the window. I'm trying to use this as transcription software, so I need to be able to control the playback when I'm typing in a word processor. If you know how to make those accessible even from outside the window, that would be even better. Thanks for your help though!